# bundled aurelia app loads too slow

Tags: aurelia

I've been playing around with a small app which is broken up as follows - listed in loading order:

- a css file, which also imports bootstrap (size 124KB, 1.8s)
- an "aurelia.js" file which contains all aurelia code (320KB, 1.8s)
- a "myproject.js" file which contains my code (100KB, 0.9s)
- a "dependencies.js" file which contains various dependencies (400KB, 1.2s)

The problem is that these files seem to load *sequentially*, taking around six seconds. How can I fix this?

Comment: I notice your files are quite large. If you use debug mode in your browser, have you disabled network throttling?

Comment: what does your setup look like? Are you using systemjs?

Comment: Sounds like your machine is having problems running as a web server actually.  The sizes of the files, especially when gzipped on a real server, will mean they are loaded it shouldn't take more than about 30-80ms each to load.

Comment: You are right, times given are on a laptop. But the main question is if the loading of files may be parallelised (yes, I'm using systemjs)